# Why are some .h files missing when compiling wbrtc_ios as a framework?

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-ios

I am new to WebRTC stuff. I cloned the webrtc_ios main branch, and I built the framework as instructed [here](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/) with the python script for arm64. When I add this to my Xcode project as a framework, everything is fine. Project builds, I can import files using <WebRTC/...> syntax.

However, I need to use RTCMTLRendeder.h file. Building a framework with python script leaves some of the header files out. (When I take a look at WebRTC.h inside the built framework, I can see that this file is missing) How can I include all header files that actually exist inside /webrtc_ios/src/sdk/objc/components folder while building the framework? I can see RTCMTLRenderer.h and .mm files are in that folder before using the build script. When turned into a framework those files don't exist inside the framework anymore. Why? And is there any other way to actually copy those files into the project as well?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to create your own, long renderer class which does not inherit from RTCMTLRenderer at all if you want to render on Metal view manually in a Swift/ObjC hybrid project (at least this is how I solved it). That class does whatever RTCMTLRenderer does, and grabs pixel buffers from RTCVideoTrack through an RTCVideoView.